# No reachable servers source=“connection.go:86”

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, prometheus

I am setting up prometheus mongodb exporter in standalone server. My mongodb is running on localhost:27017 and expose at localhost:9216 but the mongodb_up is still 0.

> ERRO[0000] Cannot connect to server using url http://test:testing@localhost:27017/admin: no reachable servers source=“connection.go:86”
> ERRO[0000] Can’t create mongo session to http://test:testing@localhost:27017/admin source=“mongodb_collector.go:202”
> FATA[0000] listen tcp localhost::9216: bind: address already in use source=“server.go:122”

here is prometheus config

scrape_configs:

```
job_name: “mongodb_exporter”
static_configs:
targets: [“localhost:9090” , “localhost:9216”]
```

I've tried all, and I'm hoping for help

Comment: `address already in use` - have you determined what is already listening on the address you are trying to bind to?

Comment: Before making the executable, I do the following:

export MONGODB_URI=mongodb://test:testing@localhost:27017
and then

 /usr/local/bin/mongodb_exporter

Is that what you meant?